# Porting a Netbeans JavaFx project to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, javafx, eclipse-juno

I'm working on a JavaFx project on NetBeans 7.3 my question is : Is it possible to port a Netbeans JavaFx project to eclipse (juno preferably) successfully, what are the issues I may face, and if it is possible what is the best way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the plugins provided by e(fx)clipse: http://www.efxclipse.org/

Comment: Actually I'm aware of e(fx)clipse since it's the most common way to create JavaFx Apps in Eclipse, what I am worried about is : is it possible to port a already created project in Netbeans to Eclipse (using of course e(fx)clipse plugin)